# Install mongodb as a service on Windows 8

Tags: windows, mongodb, service, windows-8

I am trying to install `mongodb` as a service on `Windows 8`.

I am using the following command to install `Mongodb`.

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --auth --config C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg --install
```

And I am getting this error:

```
 Wed Mar 13 19:13:23 Trying to install Windows service 'MongoDB'
 Wed Mar 13 19:13:23 Error connecting to the Service Control Manager: Access is denied. (5)
```

How can I install the `Mongodb` Service?

I tried this using Administrator privileges but the problem is still not solved.

Comment: Please make sure that, the command prompt on which you running this command is running as `Run as Administrator` option.

Comment: I  Running as Administrator but the problem not solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was occuring because the file `mongod.cfg` was not properly edited. Mongodb normally edits the content of `mongod.cfg` by itself but on windows 8 this did not work. And therefore this error showed up. I solved this problem by manually configuring the file and adding below code into the `mongod.cfg` file. Then I tried again and now it is working for me:

```
logpath=C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log
logappend=true
dbpath = /mongodb/data/db
```

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that, the command prompt on which you running this command is running as `Run as Administrator` option.

Comment: I Running as Administrator but the problem not solve

Comment: This seems like a Permission error. Please make sure that you have correct administrative privileges

Comment: I an sure about  cmd that is running as  Administrator